# Почему не выводиться ключ вложенного массива при поиске?

Tags: php

Есть задача

```
Написать функцию которая принимает два аргумента, первый массив а вторым значение для поиска.
В случае если значение было найдено возвращает его ключ иначе false.
пользоваться стандартной функцией для поиска в массиве нельзя. Учтите что массив может быть многомерный. Использовать рекурсию.
```

Вот как ее решил:

```
function find(array $arr,$someVar){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$var){// циклом проходимся по массиву
        if(is_array($var)){// если итератор тоже массив, то рекурсивно вызывается функция find
            find($var,$someVar);
        }
        elseif($var===$someVar){
                return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(find(['a',['b',6,'e'],'c','b'],'e'));
```

Почему возвращает false? Подскажите пожалуйста где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Возьмите в руки отладку ↑↑↑ и пройдитесь по коду. В разработке её очень часто используют

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить возможность возврата результата рекурсивного вызова

```
function find(array $arr, $someVar)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $var) {
        // циклом проходимся по массиву
        if (is_array($var)) {
            // если итератор тоже массив, то рекурсивно вызывается функция find
            $k = find($var, $someVar);
            // return when recursive call fund key
            if ($k) {
                return $k;
            }
        } elseif ($var === $someVar) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[PHP recursive function online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/bb5448386f4f901baf591543e9b7b760/)